# drop-down list from a database asp .net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using asp .net mvc 4. I have a database that contains a table of **users(user_id, password, email)** , another one for **roles(role_id,role_description)** , and a table i called **user_role(user_id,role_id)** that contains the list of users with their roles and i'm using entity framework for the model. I have a controller for user account settings with 3 views, one for creating one for editing and one for deleting a user. The problem is that all of those views are strongly-typed to the **user model** and i want to update the table role and the table user_role at the same time. How can i do? if you want i can show you more details.
i'm wondering if there is a way to show a drop-down list for the roles s that users can choose one role from the existing roles in the database.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a UserViewModel class that will hold all required information in the particular view like List of available roles that will be shown in your drop down, selected role and so on. Something like that

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }


        public int RoleId { get; set; }


        public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

your view header in your *.cshtml file will be look like

```
@model Namespace.UserViewModel
```

Set this class as Model for your User View and go ahead.